# Share cacerts, truststore across multiples nodes of Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

K8s n00b here.
How would a java app that can have multiple pods, across nodes, use the same cacerts, truststore across?

Should I take some different approach?

My use-case is that an admin of that app can add a cert./key to these truststore, cacerts, and it needs to be used (propagated?) to all the apps using them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use some approachs to distribute the files between pods:

If the file is open just for **read**, you can create a [configMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) to store the file, and them [mount the configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) in all your pods.

If the file is open to **read/write**, you can use [PersistVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) using NFS or if you are using some cloud provider, there is a possibility to attach volumes in your pods ([see here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes)) like EBS to AWS and GCP Persistent Disk be mount in all the pods for read/write.

There is no "correct way" all depends of how your application works.

Comment: our solution looks like to encode it as Secret, and mount its files where needed.

Comment: Yes, it is totally valid, depending the file type you can use configmap or secrets.